# Adding dates for unique EIDs row-wise to get Years of Service

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, date

I have the following dataset:

| EID | Company | Start_Date | End_Date | T_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A111 | ABC | 2015-07-20 | NaT | True |
| B111 | DEF | 1983-06-01 | NaT | False |
| B111 | ABC | 2017-01-01 | NaT | True |
| C111 | GHI | 1980-10-01 | 1981-08-31 | True |
| D111 | JKL | 1973-05-01 | 1977-11-30 | True |
| E111 | ABC | 2006-04-24 | NaT | True |
| F111 | ABC | 1991-06-10 | 1994-12-15 | False |
| F111 | MNO | 1994-12-01 | 2002-08-31 | False |
| F111 | ABC | 2002-08-01 | NaT | True |
| G111 | ABC | 1979-01-01 | NaT | True |
| H111 | ABC | 2002-02-01 | NaT | True |

The expected output is as follows:

| EID | Company | Start_Date | End_Date | T_F | YoS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A111 | ABC | 2015-07-20 | NaT | True | NaN |
| B111 | DEF | 1983-06-01 | NaT | False | (2017-01-01) - (1983-06-01) |
| B111 | ABC | 2017-01-01 | NaT | True | NaN |
| C111 | GHI | 1980-10-01 | 1981-08-31 | True | (1981-08-31) - (1980-10-01) |
| D111 | JKL | 1973-05-01 | 1977-11-30 | True | (1977-11-30) - (1973-05-01) |
| E111 | ABC | 2006-04-24 | NaT | True | NaN |
| F111 | ABC | 1991-06-10 | 1994-12-15 | False | (2002-08-01) - (1991-06-10) |
| F111 | MNO | 1994-12-01 | 2002-08-31 | False | NaN |
| F111 | ABC | 2002-08-01 | NaT | True | NaN |
| G111 | ABC | 1979-01-01 | NaT | True | NaN |
| H111 | ABC | 2002-02-01 | NaT | True | NaN |

This is what I am trying to do:

1. Where an EID has only one record and company is ABC YoS column should be NULL. End_Date is always blank in these cases.
2. Where an EID has multiple records and his/her last record is company ABC then YoS column will be Start date of first company - Start date of ABC company.
3. Where an EID has only one record and company is not ABC then YoS will be calculated as End_Date - Start_Date
4. Only the first record will have YoS value other records will contain NaN value.
5. If an employee has multiple records 99% of the times employees last records will be ABC company.

I tried the following code but this is only half part (or incorrect) I believe:

```
 result.loc[~(result.CLEAN_NAME == 'HONEYWELL / HON') & (result.T_F == False),'Hon_StartDate'] = result['Start_Date']
```

Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best solution, but it gets the job done. Considering the input is a CSV file stored in `company.csv` and using `groupby` on `EID`:

```py
from itertools import chain
import pandas as pd

def compute_yos(record):
    if len(record) == 1 and record.iloc[0]["Company"] == "ABC":
        return [pd.NaT]
    elif len(record) > 1 and record.iloc[-1]["Company"] == "ABC":
        yos = [record.iloc[-1]["Start_Date"] - record.iloc[0]["Start_Date"]]
        return yos + [pd.NaT] * (len(record) - 1)
    elif len(record) == 1 and record.iloc[0]["Company"] != "ABC":
        return [record.iloc[0]["End_Date"] - record.iloc[0]["Start_Date"]]
    else:
        return [pd.NaT] * len(record)

input_df = pd.read_csv("company.csv")
print(input_df)
input_df[["Start_Date", "End_Date"]] = input_df[["Start_Date", "End_Date"]].apply(
    pd.to_datetime
)

grouping = input_df.groupby(["EID"]).apply(compute_yos)
concat_grouping = chain.from_iterable(grouping)
input_df["YoS"] = list(concat_grouping)
print(input_df)
```

input:

```
     EID Company Start_Date   End_Date    T_F
0   A111     ABC 2015-07-20        NaT   True
1   B111     DEF 1983-06-01        NaT  False
2   B111     ABC 2017-01-01        NaT   True
3   C111     GHI 1980-10-01 1981-08-31   True
4   D111     JKL 1973-05-01 1977-11-30   True
5   E111     ABC 2006-04-24        NaT   True
6   F111     ABC 1991-06-10 1994-12-15  False
7   F111     MNO 1994-12-01 2002-08-31  False
8   F111     ABC 2002-08-01        NaT   True
9   G111     ABC 1979-01-01        NaT   True
10  H111     ABC 2002-02-01        NaT   True
```

output:

```
     EID Company Start_Date   End_Date    T_F        YoS
0   A111     ABC 2015-07-20        NaT   True        NaT
1   B111     DEF 1983-06-01        NaT  False 12268 days
2   B111     ABC 2017-01-01        NaT   True        NaT
3   C111     GHI 1980-10-01 1981-08-31   True   334 days
4   D111     JKL 1973-05-01 1977-11-30   True  1674 days
5   E111     ABC 2006-04-24        NaT   True        NaT
6   F111     ABC 1991-06-10 1994-12-15  False  4070 days
7   F111     MNO 1994-12-01 2002-08-31  False        NaT
8   F111     ABC 2002-08-01        NaT   True        NaT
9   G111     ABC 1979-01-01        NaT   True        NaT
10  H111     ABC 2002-02-01        NaT   True        NaT
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.! Just one thing...if I don't use concat will I get the actual subtracted values.? If not what change should be made to get those.?

Comment: Oh, I thought you just needed the string representation of dates. To subtract the dates, convert the `Start_Date` and `End_Date` columns to `datetime`. Then, the subtraction will give you a Python `Timedelta` object to work with. I edited my answer, so it subtracts the dates.

Comment: Thank you so much for eiditing the answer.! I am out because of medical emergencies. Will try it out on my original dataset once I get back. Will upvote the answer as well.!

Comment: It worked for my original dataset. Thanks a lot.! and sorry for late comments and acceptance.